# How do I get Vue CLI to use an external HTML file with hot reloading?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've used the default vue-cli to scaffold a Vue project. I'd like to use the Vue application in the context of a different HTML file.

I have a file called `dashboard.html` is served by the application at localhost:8000. The Vue CLI serves everything at localhost:3000. My HTML file normally includes scripts from `/public/scripts/`. Therefore, the Vue project should be included from `/public/scripts/myproject.js`

How would I configure my Vue project so that the actual files are generated into the location mentioned above and I'm able to use my custom HTML file? With a scenario like this, is it still possible to achieve hot-code reloading as the default Vue scaffolding provides?

Comment: Also looking for a solution here. I think when you use the dev server the files are not actually built on the file system, but rather are in-memory.

In my case I have a server-rendered html file that has some in-page global variables (like site features, current user, and a routing map) so the template needs to be populated by a server render before the vue app bootstraps into it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your solution by using iframe

`<iframe id="theIframe" src="http://localhost:8080" ></iframe>`

In case of hot-reloading, if your app that runs on localhost:8080 has the hot-reload functionality, than it can hot reload on iframe